# Why the Lookup function in SSRS is failing

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have two tables in my database as follows:

```sql
SELECT TOP 12 [Date], [Amount]
FROM [Db].[dbo].[final]
UNION
SELECT MAX([F1]) 'Date', SUM([F2]) 'Amount' FROM (
  SELECT TOP 5 [F1], [F2]
  FROM [Db].[dbo].[origtable]
  WHERE [F1] IS NOT NULL
  ORDER BY [F1] DESC
) c

SELECT TOP 12 [date_period2] AS [Date], [trnchargeamt] AS [Amount]
FROM [Db].[dbo].[othertable]
ORDER BY [date_period2] DESC
```

Which displays the following (first query is the top and second query is the bottom):

```
Date                     Amount
2013-07-31 00:00:00.000  9658254
2013-08-31 00:00:00.000  6659659
2013-09-30 00:00:00.000  14256326
2013-10-31 00:00:00.000  8912215
2013-11-30 00:00:00.000  9326659
2013-12-31 00:00:00.000  10211985
2014-01-31 00:00:00.000  8652365
2014-02-28 00:00:00.000  16256326
2014-03-31 00:00:00.000  24454342
2014-04-30 00:00:00.000  16345908
2014-05-30 00:00:00.000  6976515.77
2014-05-30 00:00:00.000  23578640

Date    Amount
201406  42492.78
201405  1846703.374
201405  44390961.65
201404  45413273.91
201403  46943807.39
201402  33744223.24
201401  41630266.94
201312  40672523.92
201311  42465408.47
201310  47878730.59
201309  39444986.25
201308  40554376.28
```

In my SSRS I have it like the following way to display the charts:

[image: report layout]

I am using the following lookup function to display the first table with the second table:

```
=Lookup(Fields!Date.Value,Fields!Date.Value, Fields!Amount.Value, "WMGDailyPaymentsRed")
```

I get the following warning and nothing is displayed for the second chart:

> [rsRuntimeErrorInExpression] The Y expression for the chart ‘Chart8’ contains an error:
>   Exception of type 'Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportProcessingException_ComparisonError' was thrown.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see from the results of your select statement the first SQL.. has an actual Date and the second sql has a date period with just year and month.. hence comparing both would not work. You would need to modify your first query to format the date into YYYYMM format and then it would work in the lookup.

Comment: I realized that when I just used that as the only query and tried to format it and it returned NULL. Thank you :)